# Parse world weather online JSON with ObjectiveC for iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I need a suggestion: I've a JSON downloaded from this http://www.worldweatheronline.com/free-weather.aspx. I've issue to parse this JSON:

```
{
   "data":{
      "current_condition":[
         {
            "cloudcover":"0",
            "humidity":"57",
            "observation_time":"07:23 PM",
            "precipMM":"0.0",
            "pressure":"1013",
            "temp_C":"23",
            "temp_F":"73",
            "visibility":"10",
            "weatherCode":"113",
            "weatherDesc":[
               {
                  "value":"Clear"
               }
            ],
            "weatherIconUrl":[
               {
                  "value":"http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0008_clear_sky_night.png"
               }
            ],
            "winddir16Point":"W",
            "winddirDegree":"275",
            "windspeedKmph":"0",
            "windspeedMiles":"0"
         }
      ],
      "request":[
         {
            "query":"Roma, Italy",
            "type":"City"
         }
      ],
      "weather":[
         {
            "date":"2013-05-04",
            "precipMM":"0.0",
            "tempMaxC":"26",
            "tempMaxF":"78",
            "tempMinC":"13",
            "tempMinF":"55",
            "weatherCode":"113",
            "weatherDesc":[
               {
                  "value":"Sunny"
               }
            ],
            "weatherIconUrl":[
               {
                  "value":"http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
               }
            ],
            "winddir16Point":"WSW",
            "winddirDegree":"251",
            "winddirection":"WSW",
            "windspeedKmph":"9",
            "windspeedMiles":"6"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

From this JSON I need 3 info: tempMaxC, tempMinC and weatherIconUrl --> value. Until now I made this method:

```
- (void)wheaterDidFinish:(NSDictionary*)object {
    if (object) {
        NSDictionary *obj = [object objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSArray *firstZero = [obj objectForKey:@"weather"];
        NSLog(@"%@ e %d", firstZero, firstZero.count);

    }
}
```

How I can obtain the info I need? Can you help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)wheaterDidFinish:(NSDictionary*)object 
{
    NSString *tempMaxC=@"" , tempMinC =@"" , weatherIconUrl =@"";

    if (object) 
    {
         NSDictionary *obj = [object objectForKey:@"data"];

         NSArray *firstZero = [obj objectForKey:@"weather"];

         NSMutableDictionary *weatherDict = [firstZero objectAtIndex:0];

         tempMaxc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[weatherDict objectForKey:@"tempMaxC"]];

         tempMinC = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[weatherDict objectForKey:@"tempMinC"]];

         NSArray *weatherIconArray=[weatherDict objectForKey:@"weatherIconUrl"];

         weatherIconUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[weatherIconArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"value"]];

    }
}
```

This will solve your problem